# Windows 8 Unable to perform hibernate

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, hibernate, backtrack

Windows 8 Enterprise edition x86. Already enabled hibernate option, to have it on shutdown menu (start menu?) and set to hibernate on lid closing. However it's not hibernating for me. When I'm trying to sleep, it's sleep fine and wake up like a kid. But when I'm demanding hibernate, it disconnects internet, turn off screen and be back to lock screen in one second.

Steps I've tried.

- Complete shutdown
- Clear hiberfile.sys by disabling and enabling back
- Resetting my power settings.

Causes I suspect:

1. Had dual boot with BackTrack with Windows 8 GUI boot manager.
2. It was fine until I reinstall BackTrack, bootmgr resetted and I'm in Ubuntu boot menu;.
3. Using additional hard disk through USB cable.(But it's not a problem before few days, however)

How to make my system to hibernate and wakeup again.

Comment: I would replace the boot manager with the Windows 8 boot manager.  Much of the hybrid shutdown is based on it being there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting boot manager to Windows 8 GUI Boot fixed the problem. Actually there is no way to have Ubuntu or any linux OS on Windows 8 boot menu as it's preloaded into memory before boot menu screen appears. However there is a workaround to do that.

- Install NeoGrub loader from EasyBCD.
- Install Grub2 with custom name from EasyBCD
- Remove the NeoGrub entry. (Optional)
- Restoring Win 8 GUI boot: [How to restore windows 8 GUI boot-loader after installing windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7)

So it will load Win 8 normally, whereas if you choose your custom linux entry, Neogrub will look for the grub boot menu and you will be presented by Ubuntu or whatever linux you have.

Finally I solved problem myself. Thanks to @Ramhound