# How Do I Restore Windows 8 as default at OS Selection Screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot, multi-boot

After a long process of getting Windows 7 Pro installed on GPT/UEFI hardware to dualboot with Windows 8 Pro, I have ran into one minor problem.

After Windows 7 was installed, it was set as the default OS. I changed that through MSconfig. During the restart process [Windows 7 boot manager](http://pix.cbabb.co/hR3Hxmtu) was displayed instead of [Windows 8 OS Selection](http://pix.cbabb.co/xZ9zuXGh). Windows 7 notes it's '*EMS Enabled*'. I'm trying to revert it to 8's boot screen.

In case this helps:
HP Sleekbook 6 preloaded with Windows 8 Core. HDD wiped clean with purchased Windows 8 Pro as fresh install.

**DISK 0**

1. OEM Partition
2. EFI Partition
3. OS 8 Pro
4. OS 7 Pro

As a side note: I previously had Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64 as the second OS. During the OS selection, Windows 8 was the default boot loader. From there I could choose Windows 8 or Ubuntu. I had manually added Ubuntu through EasyBCD. Worked with no errors. Got rid of Ubuntu due to incompatible hardware.

Comment: Have you tried running Automatic Repair from the Win8 Setup media?

Comment: It only offered to do a _System Restore_ from the many available.

Comment: Under [Repair your computer / Troubleshoot / Advanced options](http://www.winhelp.us/repair-your-computer-in-windows-8.html) don't you see the Automatic Repair option?

Comment: Yes it's there on both installation media and through the loaded OS.

Comment: - Runs automatic repair.
- No issues found
- Offers Restore point instead

Comment: Have you tried the solutions listed for http://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7, http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader etc. already?

Comment: I have tried this option http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader and it did not work, but I will try the other you listed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## **Problem:**

Installing Windows 7 rewrote the Windows 8 graphical bootloader.

---

There are several different methods you can try to restore the Windows 8 Bootloader as the default one.

## **Method One: Command line withing Windows 8**

1. Open an elevated command prompt *inside Windows 8*, you can do this from opening the context menu of cmd.exe and clicking *Run as Administrator*
2. Then run the following command:

   > bcdboot C:\Windows

Where *C* is the partition Windows 8 is currently located on

The command will replace the boot files with the ones from Windows 8, set the Windows 8 menu entry as the default one and set the parameters in the BCD to the default ones hence next time you reboot you'll see the graphical menu.

---

## **Method Two: EasyBCD - GUI method**

There is a GUI tool directly available [here](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) - You could try setting Windows 8 as your *default OS* - From what I understand, you've already done this using MSConfig, but you could retry this from EasyBCD, it's worked for me before.