# Will not display option of Windows 8 or Windows 7

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

I just installed Windows 7 alongside Windows 8. Now I cant boot Windows 8 because it automaticaly boots Windows 7 without displaying boot menu.

How can I get menu with options to choose which Os to boot?

Comment: I would install easyBCD free version. It adds it's own grub menu that you can customize from windows and makes switching back and forth really easy.

Comment: You installed windows 7 after 8? If so, boot form you Windows 8 media and "repair" the Windows installation.  Window s is pretty friendly about it though, so are you SURE you didn't delete/overwrite your Windows 8 install by accident?  Have you tried booting form your Win 8 install media and repairing the boot yet?

Comment: Related: [How to restore windows 8 GUI boot-loader after installing windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: TECHIE007..I INSTALLED BCD.  YES I INSTALLED WIN 7 AFTER 8.  I READ THE ABOVE LINK..MINE DOES NOT LOOK LIKE THAT...THE ONLY WAY I CAN SEE WIN 8 IS IF I GO INTO RECOVERY (I ADMIT I DONT KNOW A LOT ABOUT WIN 8).  I AM NOT SURE IF I DELETED OVERWROTE OR JUST DONT KNOW A WAY TO ACCESS.  I DONT SEE IT UNDER SYS STARTUP.  I AM GOING TO TRY THE BOOT WIN 8 MEDIA AND REPAIR.  **I JUST HOPE I DONT DELETE 7 WHEN DOING SO.  THANKS TEEZ

Answer (score 0):

Login with windows 7 and follow the steps.
My computer right click -> system Properties -> Advance tab -> system and recovery -> settings -> Under System startup, choose a default operating system and the amount of time to display the list of operating systems, click OK, and then click OK again.You can also verify the boot.ini file information, whether the windows 8 OS path added correctly. To know more on this, please refer the below URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550245(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vembu I tried the above. The only choice is 7. I tried to post a screen shot of system start up and disk manager (site would not allow). it is hp 6g 2249 with UEFI.  I have ran dual os before and have never encountered this.