# Keep Metro bootloader when Windows 7 is set as default

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, modern-ui, windows-10-preview

Recently I installed `Windows 10 Technical Preview` as a second OS, and I dual-boot it with `Windows 7`. I have `UEFI` setup, with `Secure Boot` disabled. Every time I set `Windows 7` as the default OS I lose the Metro bootloader(I get the ugly black-white bootscreen). How can I keep the new bootloader and still use `Windows 7` as the default OS, preferably with timer set to 5 seconds?

Comment: Switch the order, install windows 10 then windows 7

Comment: @Ramhound don't think that helps: http://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7

Comment: Sure it does; because it's much easier to then go back to the newer Bootloader

Comment: @Ramhound anyways wiping my machine is not an option

Comment: Your running a preview version of windows with absolutely no upgrade path which will expire in less than 8 months.  But the solution is the same of course.  You need to use the Windows 10 WinRE to replace the bootloader, the answer you linked to, can be used as a guide.