# How to Using Metro Boot Manager on UEFI BIOS when Dual Boot with Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, gpt

I have a problem when trying to set up dual boot (Windows 10 + Linux Mint 17) in UEFI mode or on a GPT disk.

I cannot go back to using the default Windows 10 boot manager?

In Legacy mode or on MBR usualy I used EasyBCD.

How can I go back to the default Windows 10 boot manager on this Windows 10 & Linux installation, on my UEFI+GPT formatted drive, and keep Windows 10 as the first and default option?

[image: Sample picture of Bootmanager]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore windows 8 GUI boot-loader after installing windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: No, this is different, if you install windows and linux on UEFI or GPT still can not using easyBCD, or fix MBR.

Comment: If you are familiar with EasyBCD it has an option to install metro bootloader on disk (which does the same as the procedure explained in linked answer). You can use it too.

Comment: EasyBCD is not working with UEFI or GPT partitions. Can you tell me which the method can work with UEFI or GPT on Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux using Windows 10 bootmanager..?

Comment: You can change the EFI boot order with tools like `bcdedit` or [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows, `bcfg` in an EFI shell, or `efibootmgr` in Linux. These tools will enable you to set the Windows boot manager as the default. From there, configuring the Windows boot manager to chainload to GRUB (or whatever you're using to boot Mint) is a separate question. I know next to nothing about configuring the Windows boot manager, so I can't comment on that. There are numerous alternatives, though; see [my Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/).

Comment: Hi @RodSmith, thanks for your explanations..
I mean isn't only set windows 10 boot by default, but add linux option on windows 10 boot menu in UEFI mode. and make the windows 10 boot manager (Metro Style) for 1st boot not linux grub.
Can you tech me about this..?