# Windows 10 - any way to invoke Metro boot loader from the Legacy one?

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10, I would like to be able to start/invoke the Metro (pretty blue-white) bootloader menu from the Legacy (less pretty black-white) bootloader menu.
Is there any way this can be done?
Although the Metro bootloader has lots of additional options not found in the Legacy version, there are 2 reasons I want the Legacy bootloader to load first and then give me the option to invoke the Metro version if I need it.

1. I can hit CTL-ATL-DEL from Legacy menu and quickly reset the computer.  You cannot do this from the Metro one.  Believe me, during certain testing that requires lots of rebooting this can be a huge timesaver.
2. The Legacy version will not crash before you get to it when you do things like switch from IDE to AHCI or RAID on your SATA ports.  This gives you the option of being able to still load the Legacy bootloader and choose Safe Mode, where you can easily straighten the situation out; but with the Metro bootloader you just crash hard and never get a menu to be able to do anything about it.
   Therefore, I think it would be optimal to start with the Legacy bootloader menu and have the option, if need be, to quickly launch the Metro bootloader from it without any fuss.
   I cannot figure out how to do this though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore windows 8 GUI boot-loader after installing windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/499675/how-to-restore-windows-8-gui-boot-loader-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: Which Bootloader are you seeing right now? Due to the way Bootloaders work, I'm not sure you can "nest" them the way you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I have to answer my own question to address the two comments.
I thought I was very clear.
I don't want to RESTORE the GUI (Metro) boot loader; I already know how to switch to using that one permanently.  Instead, I want to be able to INVOKE the Metro bootloader from the Legacy bootloader, which is what I am (happily, mostly) using now.
I simply want to chain to the Metro bootloader from the Legacy one if it suits me to do that ... if it's somehow possible.

Comment: You’ll have a much better time at [SE] (the overall system of which [SF] and [SU] are pieces) if you register an account. As long as you’re logged in to [SU], I suggest that you (1) register your account here, (2) go to [SF], (3) click “Join this community”, (4) go to [the Contact page](/contact), and (5) select “I need to merge user profiles”. You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: It's a simple question.  I didn't think I needed to go through setting up an account, and it seems I can comment here now.